# Hide flutter local notification on foreground

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I want to hide notification when app is in foreground but IOS is showing notification even in foreground. Normally FCM notification are not shown when app is in foreground.
Here is my code

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings =
        IOSInitializationSettings();

    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);

    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    final bool? result = await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            IOSFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.requestPermissions(
          alert: true,
          badge: true,
          sound: true,
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to add this line

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: false,
    badge: false,
    sound: false,
  );
```

Comment: The question was regarding `FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin` not `FirebaseMessaging`.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for iOS.

When you initialize `IOSInitializationSettings` you have those params:

`presentAlert`: Display an alert when the notification is triggered while app is in the foreground.
`presentSound`: Play a sound when the notification is triggered while app is in the foreground.
`presentBadge`: Apply the badge value when the notification is triggered while app is in the foreground.

So if you set those params to `false`, notifications should be shown on background and hidden on foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's against google play policy to run a foreground service without notification because the user needs to know which app is consuming memory on the device.
But lets say you are using https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service  for services and https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications for notification.  you can trick the service in removing the sticky notification but it will show at the start of service. i only tested this trick on android 10
First initialize service with the same channel key as Awesome_notifications

```
Future<void> main() async {
  await initializeService();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

Future<void> initializeService() async {
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  const notificationChannelId = 'com_example_channel_id';
  // initialize awesome notifications
  await NotificationController.initializeLocalNotifications(notificationChannelId);
  ////
  const notificationId = 888;
  await service.configure(
    androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
      onStart: onStart,
      autoStart: true,
      autoStartOnBoot: true,
      isForegroundMode: true,
      initialNotificationTitle: "",
      initialNotificationContent: "",
      notificationChannelId: notificationChannelId,
      foregroundServiceNotificationId: notificationId,
    ),
    iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
      onForeground: onStart,
    ),
  );
}
```

In the onStart method remove the channel and re-initialize the notification again

```
   @pragma('vm:entry-point')
    Future<void> onStart(ServiceInstance service) async {
      // Only available for flutter 3.0.0 and later
      DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();
      const notificationChannelId = 'com_example_channel_id';
      // remove channel 
      await AwesomeNotifications()
          .removeChannel(notificationChannelId);
      await 
    NotificationController.initializeLocalNotifications(notificationChannelId);
   /// your code goes here 
}
```

In the NotificationController class add this code

```
class NotificationController {
     static Future<void> initializeLocalNotifications(String notificationChannelId) async {
    // init notification channel
        await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
          "resource://drawable/ic_bg_service_small",
          [
            NotificationChannel(
              channelKey: notificationChannelId,
              channelName: 'My notification Updates',
              channelDescription: 'My notification Updates',
              playSound: true,
              onlyAlertOnce: true,
              importance: NotificationImportance.High,
              defaultPrivacy: NotificationPrivacy.Private,
              defaultColor: Colors.blue,
              ledColor: Colors.blue,
              icon: "resource://drawable/ic_bg_service_small",
            )
          ],
          debug: true,
        );
    
        // Get initial notification action is optional
        initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
            .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
      }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this trick with FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin and i hope google hasn't patched this yet, you must first confirm.

**Note:** Since the service will make a notification but for a short time after it is started, you can use different notification initialization setting like removing sound, changing notification priority on the first
**Disclaimer** This might not work in some cases. Awesome notification must recreate the removed channel before you make any notification or else the app will crush

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to see the notifications in foreground, then add your code to **only** the `onBackgroundMessage` handler.

Comment: Yes it  is defined in background message only

Comment: ok. you will still receive notifications but the notifications header won't show.